# "Module not found: Can't resolve..." to custom module - TS2307

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

We've inherited a Next + TypeScript site from another developer and we're trying to create a new component that's based very heavily from one that already exists.
I've copied the entire component and sub folders to the same level as the existing one, but if I then change the reference to the cloned folder, I get the "Module not found: Can't resolve" error:

```
import { MyModule } from '@project-root/shared/foo/bar/old/module';
```

works, but

```
import { MyModule } from '@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module';
```

in the same file, doesn't. But the contents of the 'new' folder is directly copied from the 'old' folder.

I've copied the reference to the path to the tsconfig.base.json and restarted but it's not being found:

```
"@project-root/shared/foo/bar/old/module": [
   "libs/shared/foo/bar/old/module/src/index.ts"
],
"@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module'": [
   "libs/shared/foo/bar/new/module/src/index.ts"
],
```

What's the cause of the issue, and how can it be resolved?

Comment: Paths need to be configured also in webpack. ts-loader mostly does it. But your tsconfig file name isn't the default one. If you use webpack and ts-loader, try to use loader like this
{
   loader: 'ts-loader',
   options: {
       configFile: "tsconfig.base.json"
   }
}

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't see that ts-loader is being called in  that way, and the tsconfig.base.json is extended by multiple tsconfig.json throughout the project.

It did lead me to try running `tsc --traceResolution` but that just returned the same error that I'm seeing in the code editor:

```error TS2307: Cannot find module '@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module' or its corresponding type declarations.```

Not sure if that helps see what's going on?

Comment: Maybe your new/module is a js file, and ts can't find just declaration. If it's like that, you can try to use declare module "yourfilepath" in any .d.ts file, maybe it will help

Comment: Seems like you accidentally typed a ' at the end of ""@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module'" in your tsconfig.json... maybe that is the problem?

Comment: It sounds like the issue may be related to the way the TypeScript compiler is resolving the module paths. The compiler uses the paths specified in the "paths" property of the tsconfig.json file to determine where to look for modules.
It's possible that the old path is being resolved correctly, but the new path is not being recognized. You should double check that the new path is spelled correctly, and that it is included in the "paths" property of the tsconfig.json file.
If the problem persists, you should also check if there's any other config files that may be overwriting the path you...

Comment: @DerAnonyme OH. MY. GOD. that was it. Just didn't see that extra apopstrophe. Thank you! Could you reply as an answer and I'll award you the credit - thank you!

Comment: Don't buy your apostrophes from SO because they cost 500.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested here is my answer. The apostrophe at the end of "@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module'" is the issue. Also happened to me once, somebody else who had just looked at it found it immediatly...

Comment: glad it's not just me - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

[@DerAnonyme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20959752) found the issue. You have an extra apostrophe where you shouldn't (at the end of the path string for the new path mapping's key ("`module'`"))- I'd wager due to a bad copy-paste from the import statement:

```
"@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module'": [
   "libs/shared/foo/bar/new/module/src/index.ts"
],
```

I could repro getting the same error message.

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@project-root/shared/foo/bar/old/module": ["A.ts"],
      "@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module'": ["B.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

A.ts and B.ts

```
export const foo = 0;
```

index.ts

```
import { foo as fooA } from "@project-root/shared/foo/bar/old/module"
import { foo as fooB } from "@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module"
```

error (notice how there's no error for line 1 with the no-typo path mapping):

```
index.ts:2:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module' or its corresponding type declarations.

2 import { foo as fooB } from "@project-root/shared/foo/bar/new/module"
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

And then, removing the erroneous apostrophe character, the error goes away.

Comment: yup. that was it. Just that apostrophe on the end.